# moment.js - Previous Quarter within a Tableau Extension

Tags: momentjs

I am working with a tableau extension (Biztory: date parameter) which uses an input box for a date parameter. Instead of having the Start date being the start of this quarter, I would like to have it be the start of the previous quarter. I found a few searches on this, but it does not appear the input box allows a custom function.

Any suggestions on this? Thank you, Brent

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').startOf('quarter')
```